# How do I get my threads to run in an orderly sequence?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java threads and want my code to output threads 0-9 in sequential order. I used the synchronized keyword but  I don't get the results I expect.

What should I do to correct my code?

```java
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    private static final int threadMax = 10;
    private static int runCount = 0;

    public void printThread() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (runCount++ < 100) {
                System.out.println(runCount + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void run() {

        printThread();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < threadMax; i++) {
            new MyThread().start();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

Comment: You should not synchronize on a thread instance, and generally you should not extend Thread, but instead implement Runnable and pass that to the appropriate Thread constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It is not working as every time you are creating new `MyThread` object and you are synchronized over that new object. So, every `Thread` you created will get a lock on the **diffrent object**. So, you should pass a common object to take the lock like below.

```
class MyThread extends Thread {

    private static int runCount = 0;

    Object lock;

    public MyThread(Object lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public void printThread() {
        synchronized (lock) {
           // your code here
        }

    }

 //.........
}
```

And then call it like :

```
Object lock = new Object();
for (int i = 0; i < threadMax; i++) {
    new MyThread(lock).start();
}
```

However, the above program will not ensure you that it will run in sequence. There are several ways to do that. You can use `wait() and notify()` to achieve your goal. Refer the below example :

```
public void printThread() {

        while (runCount < 90) {
            synchronized (lock) {
                while (runCount % 10 != remainder) {

                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(runCount + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                runCount++;
                lock.notifyAll();
            }
        }

    }
```

And call the thread like :

```
    Object lock = new Object();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        new MyThread(lock, i).start();
    }
```

Comment: How would i change my code to ensure the threads run "Sequentially"?

Comment: I get the following output using the above code; 1: Thread-1
2: Thread-1
3: Thread-1
4: Thread-1
5: Thread-1
6: Thread-1
7: Thread-1
8: Thread-1
9: Thread-1
10: Thread-1
11: Thread-1
12: Thread-1
13: Thread-1 until 100. ideally i would like something like 1: Thread-1
2: Thread-1
3: Thread-1
4: Thread-1
5: Thread-1
6: Thread-1
7: Thread-1
8: Thread-1
9: Thread-1
10: Thread-2
11: Thread-2
12: Thread-2
13: Thread-2

Comment: Even if you synchronized on a common object, there still would not be a guarantee which thread first acquires the lock - it is likely the thread `start`ed first will, in fact, be scheduled first, and acquire the lock, but AFAICS it is by no means guaranteed.

Comment: @Denis yes the program does not guarantee it will not execute in sequence  as I have already mentioned in the end of the answer. You should use wait and notify for that.

Comment: @Denis I have edited my answer and added how can you use wait() and notify

Comment: @AmitBera what does the variable remainder do in the second while loop?

Comment: @Denis  It is deciding which Thread should print the number and when to wait()? So, Thread-1 will print 1,11,21,31....., Thread-2 print 2,12,22..... and Thread-3 3,13,23,33... and so on So, the remainder will decide the which thread should print what and when.

Answer (score 0):

You are synchronizing the context of the thread, which is different for each one. You should put into the `synchronized` key any common object for all diferent threads. This won't make them run in any certain secuence, just to wait each other to end.
If you want to test the `synchronized` keyword for any purpose, you could pass the constructor a **common variable** and use it in every thread:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

private static final int threadMax = 10;
private static int runCount = 0;
private Object test; //Object pointing main method

public MyThread(Object test){
 this.test = test; //This won't copy values as it is an object and not a number, string...
}

public void printThread() {
    synchronized (test) { //Same object for all threads
        while (runCount++ < 100) {
            System.out.println(runCount + ": " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

public void run() {

    printThread();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object test; //common object
    for (int i = 0; i < threadMax; i++) {
        new MyThread(test).start();
    }

}
```

}

If you want also to make them start **in order**, you should "synchronize" the loop making `wait` and `notify` calls.

Anyway, the point about multithreading is to have several threads running at the "same" time and not in sequence, as that would be the same as a linear execution.

Comment: Thanks alot Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

You have several tasks that you want to delegate to threads but have them executed sequentially.

As others have pointed out, wait & notify can help you achieve that : wait until Nth have finished then notify the next. However, if you wait/notify inside your `printThread` method, as all your threads are waiting *simultaneously* on the same lock, there is no guaranties that N+1th thread will be next. So you may have

```
1: thread-1
...
10: thread-1
11: thread-5
...
20: thread-5
21: thread-2
...
```

If that's ok for you, you're done. However, in a situation where you specifically want your threads to be ordered, what you need is a waiting queue (FIFO : First In First Out).

To achieve that, you can use the awesome `ExecutorService`. Be aware however that they hide the `Thread`s from you and picking that solution should not be at the cost of understanding the basics of them beforehand.

An `ExecutorService` is a very convenient class that can receive tasks (in the form of a Runnable, see below) and will execute them in separate Threads.

Here, I'm using a `SingleThreadExecutor` which execute the submitted tasks sequentially. So all you have to do is call it's `execute` method with your tasks as arguments, and the `ExecutorService` will run them in the right order, one after the other.

Here's what you can do with a few notes :

```
public class ThreadRunner {

    // Note : Constants are usually all uppercase in Java
    private static final int MAX_THREADS = 10;

    private final int threadName;

    public ThreadRunner(int threadName) {
        this.threadName = threadName;
    }

    public void printThread() {
        // Note: For loops are better than while when you already know the number of iterations
        for (int runCount = 0; runCount < 10; runCount++) {
            System.out.println(runCount + "th run from thread " + threadName);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
            int threadName = i + 1;
            // Submit a task to the executor
            executorService.execute(() -> new ThreadRunner(threadName).printThread());
        }

        // Nicely ask for the executor to shutdown.
        // Then wait for already submitted tasks to terminate.
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I changed a few details, here are the reasons :

### Thread creation : don't inherit from `Thread`

I would advise you not to inherit from `Thread`, but create a local instance of it, as all you need is to **use** a `Thread` ; you don't want to **be** a `Thread` :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Using Java 1.8+ lambda
        Thread lambdaThread = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Hello from a lambda in a Thread"));
        lambdaThread.start();

        // Using an anonymous class for java <1.8
        Thread anonClassThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Hello from an anonymous class in a Thread");
            }
        });
        anonClassThread.start();
    }
```

You're creating a new `Thread` passing a `Runnable` as constructor argument, using either lambda or anonymous class, depending of your Java version.

A `Runnable` is simply a portion of code that will be executed (by a Thread, in this case).

Same apply to `ExecutorService`, it's `execute` methode takes a `Runnable` which I've created through lambdas.

### Sharing `static` counter between threads

Your line `private static int runCount = 0;` is a static field, which means it is shared by all instances of the class `MyThread`. When you increase it in a thread, all threads will read (and write) to the same variable.

If your threads were running sequentially, the first would do it's 100 iterations, then when the second thread starts, `runCount` is already at 100 and you're not entering your while loop. If that wasn't intended, it may be confusing when you'll test your code.

Based on your expected output in a comment, I believe you want your threads to do 10 iterations each, not share a *pool* of 100 iterations and manage somehow to have each of them only perform 10.

### Having the name of the thread belong to each `ThreadRunner`

Small detail here : previously, you were creating 10 threads. Here, the `ExecutorService` **only creates one** that he reuse for each task you submit. So `Thread.currentThread().getName()` would always be `thread-1`. 
You wouldn't be able to see which task is running without this field.

If each task is started after the previous, you don't need 10 Threads, but a single Thread performing the 10 tasks sequentially.

I've been as complete as possible, but some points might be a little bit tricky, so don't hesitate to ask for clarifications!

Comment: You are right. I want each Thread to do 10 iterations and in an ordered manner. i.e Thread-1(10x), Thread-2(10x)....Though i would like to achieve this using low-level synchronization using only wait and notify